# visual basic debit credit entry

Tags: combinations, access-database-engine

1-Hi Sir, I have Table of General in Access Database when I make the entry like Sale and purchases payment Receipt How I bound two column (Debit and Credit) must equal than save the entry I connected database file in Visual Basic 2010.
2- I have access 4 Table and how I will update  and save data with one table adaptor from 4 table.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks my Table have ID,AccountName,Debit,Credit,Balance i set formula (Bal=Debit-Credit) i am using new record TableBindingSource.addnew and tablebindinsource.endupdate, tableadpotor.update(database.tablename) when i addnew record than only one record can add mean only debit side than after i make addnew record for credit side i want addnew same time Debit & Credit with one record for  Parallel entry with Account Name also,   (Account Name   Debit,)(Account Name Credit) i think you understand my question. Thank you